# Can the eCryptfs encrypted filename prefix be changed?

Tags: ecryptfs

If I enable filename encryption in eCryptfs, when I unmount the filesystem all my files have names which start with "ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED".  I understand the need for the file system to have a signature in the filename which it can use to identify a filename as encrypted, but I would like to use something more discreet.  Is there a way that I can change what this string is so that there aren't a bunch of files on the filesystem boldly listed as "ENCRYPTED"?  It seems like this could easily be a mount option but if there is one I am missing it.  Is there something somewhere else, like a PAM configuration file I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prefix is a constant in the kernel source:

```c
fs/ecryptfs/ecryptfs_kernel.h
188:#define ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED_FILENAME_PREFIX "ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED."
189:#define ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED_FILENAME_PREFIX_SIZE 24
```

It may just be a matter of editing those constants, recompiling the ecryptfs kernel module, and loading that.